# Display IFrame in IJulia Jupyter Notebook

Tags: julia, jupyter, ijulia-notebook

Is there a way to display an IFrame in an IJulia Jupyter notebook?

I am trying to use Plotly.jl with Jupyter.  When `plot` is called it returns a URL linking to the generated graph.

Using an IFrame should allow this to work out.

```
Plotly.plot(["z"=>rand(6,6)],["style"=>["type"=>"heatmap"]])

https://plot.ly/~astrieanna/0  # Returned URL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IJuliaPortrayals](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jbn/IJuliaPortrayals_Demo/blob/master/demo.ipynb) has an `IFrame` constructor.

```
IFrame(600, 200, "http://julialang.org")
```

At `In [15]:`

> Bring back 2003-era pages with IFrame!

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer the the posted question, but it does solve the issue with plotly.

Plotly.jl is about to undergo massive changes. One of these will be relying on the PlotlyJS.jl package for all plot generation and display.

If you want to use plotly from julia in a jupyter notebook you should use PlotlyJS.jl: https://github.com/spencerlyon2/PlotlyJS.jl

Docs here: http://spencerlyon.com/PlotlyJS.jl/